# Force mutex unlock (Possibly from a different thread)?

Tags: locking, pthreads, mutex, unlock

I know it's kind of "breaking the rules", but I'm looking for an option to **force unlock** a mutex, possibly from a different thread.

It may be considered as some kind of hacking, since it's probably not really supported by the conventional API, but is there an option like that?

One scenario that may be interesting for me is for example, in case there's a need for a cleanup, and one thread performs general cleanup, but a different thread is working on a mutex that it locked, and it's not a real option to wait for that thread to release it.

I'm using pthread mutexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destroy the mutex using [pthread_mutex_destroy(pthread_mutex_t *mutex)](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/man/pthread_mutex_destroy.txt).
The waiting (lock or trylock) will return with `EINVAL` which you may interpret as a branch to your "cleanup". Note: The mutex object is not valid anymore after this operation. But there is some danger left since: *Attempting to destroy a locked mutex results in undefined behavior.* Undefined behaviour is this sense means that YOU have to take care about this special condition. But this was your intention, so just do your cleanup branch correct, only touch things which were protected by the mutex when sure that no other thread is doing so. Afterwards *a destroyed mutex object can be reinitialized*.

Comment: Undefined behaviour does not mean that "YOU have to take care about this special condition".  It means it could do anything.  It could kill your cat or wipe your hard drive.  You are relying on an implementation detail of your implementation, one that may be different elsewhere or changed at any time.  Steer clear of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @KevinCox: The question was explicitly saying that it may be an "breaking the rules" attempt. You **may** lose your cat or you **may** have to recover your hard drive; however, an _undefined behavior_ **may** still be recoverable. As in real life: The details do matter and will set the rules for recovery.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are interested in is 'cleaning up', use a semaphore for locking - you can always stuff in an extra unit to wake up a waiting thread in order to get it to terminate.

If the process is going to close, I don't bother with cleanups anyway, unless there is some important, overriding reasons to, (a 'clean' valgrind dump is not one of them:).

Comment: +1 for the semaphore, but how can you distinguish whether its a normal "event" or the "cleanup"?

Comment: Set a 'terminateAndExit' boolean first, then signal.  Check the boolean after the semaphore wait returns.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem here related to multiple threads waiting to acquire a particular mutex.

if the case is with a thread which is holding for a really long time. The following should help and will be cleaner. It will be preferred to make the code modular and check for conditions were you can bail out in the middle of the function which is holding the mutex.

By checking for the condition at multiple places you should be able to minimize the hold time and handle all the related cases.